# Firebase downloading all data from node why ?? even with timestamp

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code snippet for firebase

```
Query recentPostsQuery = reference.child(AppConstants.WORKINDIA_JOB_NODE)
                        .orderByChild(AppConstants.TIMESTAMP)
                        .startAt(lastSyncTime);
                 recentPostsQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(jobBulKDownloadListener);
```

Even it is giving me change data from firebase server but downloading all data and consuming very high net pack.

I have printed using

```
  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);
```

This was printing whole data under the log

```
  D/WebSocket: ws_3 - ws message:
```

[image]

This is how i have detected, Spike on every call of firebase even If I am getting 0 record.

What I am doing wrong ??

Comment: Did you define an index on `AppConstants.TIMESTAMP` in your rules? Without that the client will download all data and do the filtering client-side. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Answer (score 2):

It was poblem if timestamp(one of the key) indexing.
Go to firebase panel and add key in rule section

It is very big issue if you would not add in index it will download all data and compare on client side.

I was syncing at every 3 minutes and it consumed my 200 MB in single night.

[image]